# Do something if element equals value and is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 radio buttons and I would like to hide one of them. All 3 radio buttons have the same class but different values. I wrote code like this below but it's not working because the element is hidden on every radio button. Can you help me with this? Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('input.delivery_option_radio').val('49,').is(":checked")) {
    $(".hide").css("display", "none");
    alert("test");  
  }
});
```

Comment: Use `$('input.delivery_option_radio[value=49]').is(":checked")`. As of now you are setting value

Comment: Try `$('.hide[value="49"]').hide()`

Comment: or `$('input.delivery_option_radio:checked').val() == '49,'`

Comment: @Rajesh that wouldn't check it's checked status

Comment: How the element is hidden on every radio button?

Comment: `$('input.delivery_option_radio:checked').each(function () { if ($(this).val() == "49,") ... });` Also, a class of `hide` should already hide the element. Please create a [mcve] that includes the HTML.

Comment: @Pete Thats not suppose to. I was giving a sample of how to create a selector using value property

Comment: Thank u guys for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the value, not selecting. Try this in your if statement instead:

```
if($("input.delivery_radio_option[value=49]").is(":checked")) {...}
```

Comment: Yes I used like that: 

`if($("input.delivery_option_radio[value='49,']").is(":checked"))`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong because you trying to set value of input to `49,` and hide all `.hide` elements.

You don't need to `if`, just use [Attribute Equals `[name=”value”]`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and [`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selectors to do this work.

```js
$(".delivery_option_radio[value='49']:checked").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" class="delivery_option_radio" value="48">
<input type="radio" class="delivery_option_radio" value="49" checked>
<input type="radio" class="delivery_option_radio" value="50">
```

Answer (score 0):

if your sure that value in radio buttons is "49,"  not (49)

try this:

```
$('.hide[value="49,"]').hide();
```

else

```
$('.hide[value="49"]').hide();
```